# ProgID of the outlook addin created using VSTO c#

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I am developing an addin for outlook. There I created a new form region to the appointment. To register the Form region I want to get the ProgID of my addin. I want to know where can i find the ProgID of my Addin?

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have access to the Outlook application object, you can use code below to get ProgId:

```
 COMAddIns comAddIns = application.COMAddIns;

                foreach (COMAddIn addin in comAddIns)
                {
                    if (string.Equals(addin.Description, "YOUR ADDIN NAME", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        return addin.ProgId;
                    }
                }
```